# how to make contract for a non-empty hashtable

Tags: racket, contract

Racket has a `non-empty-listof` contract but no `non-empty-hashof` contract.  Is there a way to build one?

Comment: Original Q/A: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/KGZeQtUYKUw/3cw9ExtUBwAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates can be used as contracts, so:

```
(define (non-empty-hash? x)
  (and (hash? x)
       (not (hash-empty? x))))
```

Then you can use `non-empty-hash?` as your contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can use contract logical operators like `and/c` and `not/c` to build the desired form instead of using a predicate function (Similar to the way mutable datatypes are checked for in contract):

```lisp
Welcome to Racket v8.7 [cs].
> (define (non-empty-hash/c key/c val/c)
     (and/c (hash/c key/c val/c) (not/c hash-empty?)))
> (define/contract x (non-empty-hash/c symbol? number?) (hash))
x: broke its own contract
  promised: (not/c hash-empty?)
  produced: '#hash()
  in: the 2nd conjunct of
      (and/c
       (hash/c symbol? number?)
       (not/c hash-empty?))
  contract from: (definition x)
  blaming: (definition x)
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: string:1:17
 [,bt for context]
> (define/contract x (non-empty-hash/c symbol? number?) (hash 'a 1))
> x
'#hash((a . 1))
```

or just `(and/c hash? (not/c hash-empty?))` if you don't want to constrain the key and value types.